# does setattr() and getattr() slow down the speed dramatically?

Tags: python-3.x

Today when I checked some code at the office, I found the following code. It shocked me.

```
class XXXX():
    def __init__(self, k, v):
        for i in range(len(k)):
            setattr(self, k[i], v[i])
```

Then I found that most of the classes are written in the same way. That means all the classes are the same class,the only different is their name.

In this project `setattr()` is used to set attributes and `getattr()` is used to get attributes In profile log `setattr` was called 2700 times and `getattr` was called 3800 times. The time consume was 0.003sec and 0.005sec respectively (whole process: 0.069sec).

Though I do think `setattr` and `getattr` drag down the speed, I'm not sure if a rewrite of all the code would make it better.

Does obj.attribute = value run faster than `setattr(obj,'attribute',value)`?

Comment: What happened when you profiled it with the code changed to your "faster" version?

Comment: ah no, i just used profile to test the project. im not sure if it's the root that made the program running so slowly.

Comment: Your whole process takes less than a tenth of a second. If this isn't premature optimization, I don't know what is.

Comment: it's suppose to be less than 0.01 sec,not premature optimization.

Comment: "obj.attribute = value are faster than setattr(obj,'attribute',value)" yes they are faster, setattr should be only used in special cases where it is the only way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `getattr` and `setattr` are much slower, at least at the CPU level.

Since `__init__` is only called once per object I wouldn't worry about that unless you are creating many, many objects.

If the objects' attributes are accessed many times it could be worth it to rewrite those sections.  You should do some careful profiling first, though.

Answer (score 3):

I did a small test.   It was roughly 2x slower.

```
Increment using member took 2.8221039772

Increment using attr took 5.94811701775
```

Here is my code

```
import timeit
class Dummy(object):
    __slots__ = ['testVal']
    def __init__(self):
        self.testVal = 0

    def increment_using_attr(self):
        i = getattr(self, 'testVal')
        setattr(self, 'testVal', i+1)

    def increment(self):
        self.testVal += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = Dummy()
    print "Increment using member took {0}".format(timeit.Timer(d.increment).timeit(10000000))
    print "Increment using attr took {0}".format(timeit.Timer(d.increment_using_attr).timeit(10000000))
```

Run on machine Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q9550  @ 2.83GHz